# Problem booting (Ubuntu/Windows 8)

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Here's the problem (suddenly appeared).
I turn on my pc tries to boot... The underscore blinks for some time, screen goes black and starts over again.
Goes on for some time and after a while i get:
boot0: GPT
boot0: GPT
boot0: error 
I've only left it once to go up to there i usually restart.

I tried inserting 13.04 live cd with no luck..same thing happens.
After that I inserted a Win 8 dvd which froze when the windows logo appeared(i didn't wait for very long it could have been working, it was there for like a minute).

Restarted after a couple of times and GRUB loaded properly and now im on win 8.
Also a couple of times the pc froze while on the gigabyte logo.

extra info: windows 8 and ubuntu are installed on diff hard drives.
I have a Gigabyte 970A-DS motherboard and fx6300 amd cpu, saphire 7790 gfx(i know this is useless info but why not :P).

I hope it's not the motherboard.... Any ideas? :/

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from Linux (even from a live CD) and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates.

Comment: Gust1337 you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  You will then be able to edit your question and respond to queries.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't ruin your motherboard installing Ubuntu. Chances are, you just have Secure Boot enabled (don't you just love Win8?). To fix that, boot into BIOS and toggle the Secure-Boot setting off.

Comment: I didn't mean ubuntu ruined my motherboard, im just hoping it's not a problem generated from my motherboard failing ^^
Gonna check out the secure-boot setting after i back up a few files ,thanks